# Algorithms: Cycle count to skip iterate over all items in array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

How many cycles will be needed to touch all items in an array. Given array of n items with k (k < n) being skip count.

Example:

```
n = 6
k = 1 => 1 cycle
k = 2 => 2 cycle (C1 starting at 0[0,2,4], C2 at 1[1,3,5])
k = 3 => 3 cycle (C1 - [0,3], C2 - [1,4], C3 - [2,5])
k = 4 => 2 cycle (C1 - [0,4,2] C2 - [1,5,3])
k = 5 => 1 cycle
```

Looking for non brute force approach so that input n,k would give back cycles count.

Comment: Looks like it's just the greatest common divisor of n and k.

Comment: Thanks! Looks correct.